# C++ rvalue references asssignment to lvalue reference

Tags: c++, rvalue

Let's assume having:

```
template<typename T>
T&& f(T&& t) {
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}

Presenter p;

auto x = f(std::move(p));   // x is new Presenter object - move ctor invoked
auto x = f(p);                // x is new Presenter object - copy ctor invoked
auto& x = f(p);             // x is lvalueRef, no copy / move ctor invoked
auto&& x = f(p);       // x is lvalueRef, no copy /move ctor invoked
auto&& x = f(std::move(p));   // x is rvalueRef, no copy / move ctor invoked
```

and this is quite ok, hovever for that case:

```
auto& x = f(std::move(p));  // x is lvalueRef, no copy / move ctor invoked
```

Why we are able to assing to lvalueRef rvalueRef?

For instance we cant do:

```
auto& c = 1;
```

All help appreciated

Comment: [We are not able to, as a matter of fact](https://ideone.com/U3PzvA). Are you compiling with MSVC, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, msvc - 2015 - what's wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks, for gcc it indeed is not compiling as expected.
const lvalue ref would work however here.

Comment: Yes, it would. Because we always could bind const lvalue references to r-values.

Comment: So it means that if during compilation such situation happens, then compiler must store whatever under that rvalue was somewhere until the time const reference dies - by out of scope of whatever.